# Using List(text) how not have a default value?

Tags: forms

The first entry in the List(text) field is the one that is chosen as the default.

How do we ensure that an item is selected?

The field is

```
Deal Type   field_bond_deal_type    List (text)
```

The widget is 'select list'

The values are:

```
abs|Abs
green|Green
```

There is no blank row at the start.

Comment: Was the field set as required?

Comment: Yes, it is required

Comment: If it's required it can't start with a blank/empty value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options are

- change to taxonomy. The taxonomy system allows for 'none' as an option and also requiring that 'none' not be selected
- change the widget to 'checkboxes/radio'

Changing the widget to radio was the option chosen as there are only 3 options and taxonomy is a high overhead for 3 options.

Comment: Taxonomy in these cases though is more flexible should those options ever change at all. That is one of the biggest drawbacks to using static value fields like list or radios, which does not exist if using taxonomy reference. Unsure of the overhead you're mentioning.

Comment: Yes. Taxonomy can be changed. The overhead for this application is that everything is loaded by reference to the taxonomy table. Load field, load tid, load value. It has impacts in feeds and presenting data.